# VBA Updating Excel column in one worksheet based on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets. The first worksheet has a project number and project name. The second worksheet also has a project number and a project name. The project name in the first worksheet is incorrect and needs to be updated with the project name from the second worksheet. So:

```
Worksheet 1:
ProjectId     ProjectName
1             Apple
2             Orange
3             Banana

Worksheet 2:
ProjectId     ProjectName
1             Chicken
2             Bacon
3             Beef
```

I need to create a macro that simply runs through the rows in Worksheet 2, matches to worksheet 1 based on the Project ID, and then just updates the ProjectName in worksheet 1 with the ProjectName from worksheet 2.

How can I use VBA to iterate through the rows, match on ProjectID, and update the ProjectNames in Worksheet 1 with the ProjectNames from Worksheet 2?

Comment: There is no need to use VBA. Use VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Eduardo, just use VLOOKUP like this:

- Replace the content of ProjectName on Worksheet 1 by a function similar to this one (but adapted to your specific workbook):

`=VLOOKUP(A2, sheet2!$A$2:$B$100, 2, 0)`

Then just drag this formula down. If this is final you may want to copy and then paste special with values only so that this data remains unchanged afterwards.

Comment: probably should make the lookup range absolute `=VLOOKUP(A2, sheet2!$A$2:$B$100, 2, 0)

Comment: Hi Alex, What formula do I use if I have to pull data from different workbooks?

Comment: @RakeshAnand you can simply select the range inside the workbook and Excel will put the proper syntax before the range. I think the syntax is `[absolute path]worksheet_name!range`